# Hyperlinks in helptext or tooltips in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, helptext

I want to provide a hyperlinks in my hypertext or tooltips in lightning component. Is this possible or is there any work around for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a modal, which gives you full control over what you put into it:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/

We had a requirement to open additional information related to lookup fields, and accomplished this by creating a lightning component which wraps around a standard input field, and which decorates it with additional buttons, underlines etc.

[image: Custom input field components]

You could do something similar to create a button with a question mark icon, which opens a modal with more information, including links. It would happen on click instead of mouseover, but this may be preferable depending on your use case.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonIcon/example
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/